# Which is best way to use : @ViewChild or @Output

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to share data between two direct related components (parent -child).
I came across @ViewChild and @Output. First one will have more control and coding in parent component while later need coding in child component.

Which one should we chose over other?

Comment: As stated, your question could get closed for being Opinion Based. Have you checked the Angular documentation to see what they say about each type of communication?

Comment: How tightly coupled do you want your components to be?

Comment: As per [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), each way of sharing data between components have been listed.But there is no recommendation I have seen in documentation. Please share if you have reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@ViewChild and @Output are two very different things, so it depends on exactly what you want to do.

@ViewChild gives the parent access to the child (component or element), while @Output emits an event to the parent when something in the child changes.

If you can do what you want with either of these, then I'd choose @Output, since it doesn't couple the parent and the child, it just presents a communication channel between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for @Input and @Output.

With @Input you can send data from the parent component to a child component.

With @Output you can send data from child component to its parent as an event.